# How does MVC know the member fields of an object I post to it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I see a lot of questions on how to pass an object to MVC, but I didn't see many great explanations on how MVC does it.

This process seems like magic to me - I know I can make my MVC function accept a `Car` object based on my model that has:

```
Speed
Gears
Doors
Wheels
```

As different properties within the class.

But I don't know how MVC knows that when I send a HTTPS request  from a client with a body with

```
{Speed:50,Gears:6, Doors: 4, Wheels:4}
```

and know that it's supposed to take each parameter and set it equal to my Model that has the same properties.

I apologize if my question isn't entirely clear, but it seems very much like magic to me right now. Perhaps there's a class implementation I can look at that explains it?

Comment: Through a combination of routing tables and reflection.  [See here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/models/model-binding.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should Google MVC model binding - essentially, a "Model Binder" takes the input data, and tried to create the correct class and set the correct properties. The default one does a good job if particular conventions are used when naming the input elements on the page. If the conventions are not used, or a more complex model is used, a custom model binder can be created and used.